# Adding a UIButton

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I need a `UIButton` to act as a Radio button (selection button). When the user
clicks on the button, the color should change (to indicate that the user
clicked this button), and when the user clicks the same button again (the already selected
button) the color of the button should change to the default color indicating
that the button was un-selected.

How can i do this programatically ?

There might be other alternatives to do this, but i require to use the button
to do this.

Comment: IMO that's a "toggle"... a radio is when other buttons shut the first button off.

Answer (score 3):

You can specify different images for selected and normal button states:

```
[btnName setImage:selectedImage forState:UIControlStateSelected];
[btnName setImage:normalimage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

And then in button's action method simply toggle button's state between normal and selected:

```
- (void) buttonAction:(UIButton*)sender{
    sender.selected = !sender.selected;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Put the below code in your button action.

```
if([btnName isSelected]) {
     [btnName setImage:@"SelectedImage" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
     [btnName setSelected:NO];
} else {
     [btnName setImage:@"deSelectedImage" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
     [btnName setSelected:YES];
}
```

Hope it will be useful.

Comment: Hello Devang, can we have three states of UIButton, and toggle between them?

Comment: @RahulGupta : What exactly you want to do ? Tell me some details.

Comment: //making a button which will toggle between three states
//I have done like this. do u have any other idea?

-(IBAction)btnPressed:(id)sender
{
    UIButton *btn = (UIButton*)sender;
    
    if ([btn.titleLabel.text isEqualToString:@"Yes"])
    {
        [btn setTitle:@"No" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
    else if ([btn.titleLabel.text isEqualToString:@"No"])
    {
        [btn setTitle:@"StandBy" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
    else if ([btn.titleLabel.text isEqualToString:@"StandBy"])
    {
        [btn setTitle:@"Yes" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
}

Comment: @RahulGupta : Your code will switch between three state from one-state to another in order. I dont know whats your requirement but I will suggest you to use segment control.

Comment: :Yes, I need three state of button which will be in order, and also I don't want to use segment b'coz of space issue. Is there any other idea?

Comment: @RahulGupta : Display one button and on the click of it display small popup having three buttons(radio button kind functionality). Set the title of Display button as per the selection made in popup. You can use this popup code : https://github.com/sonsongithub/PopupView